# Переменые голубого цвета и подчёркнуты хотя так не должно быть Sublime Text

Tags: sublime-text, themes

Как видно на скриншоте ниже переменые голубого цвета но должны быть белого а так же переменые подчеркнуты чего так же не должно быть. Это появилось когда я скачал тему Dracula с сайта: https://draculatheme.com/sublime

[image: Вот скрин]

Comment: Ну выберите другую тему, наверное?

Comment: Как вариант, но другие темы для меня не удобные, я привык к этой теме.